# how to false the field value by onchange in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

In My class there is a two selection field attendance and leave type when the attendance is present the leave type should be in readonly when my attendance is abscent the leave type selection field is in required and i am selecting as sick leave and i save the record when i edit the same record and i am attendance is marking as present the leave type field value should false them. I given the field in false only but the record is saved in the database...can any one help this

This is onchange function

```
@api.onchange('attendance', 'employee_id', 'attendance_date')
def onchange_attendance(self):
    if self.attendance:
        if self.attendance == 'present':

            time_in = time_out = False

            self.present = True
            self.absent = False
            self.half_day = False
            self.late = False
            self.comp_off = False
            self.leave_type = False
            self.holiday = False
            self.weekly_off = False
            self.compensation_date = False
        if self.attendance == 'absent':
            self.present = False
            self.absent = True
            self.half_day = False
            self.late = False
            self.comp_off = False
            self.holiday = False
            self.weekly_off = False
            self.compensation_date = False
        if self.attendance == 'half_day':
            self.present = False
            self.absent = False
            self.half_day = True
            self.late = False
            self.comp_off = False
            self.holiday = False
            self.weekly_off = False
            self.compensation_date = False
        if self.attendance == 'comp_off':
            self.present = False
            self.absent = False
            self.half_day = False
            self.late = False
            self.comp_off = True
            self.leave_type = False
            self.holiday = False
            self.weekly_off = False
        if self.attendance == 'holiday':
            self.present = False
            self.absent = False
            self.half_day = False
            self.late = False
            self.comp_off = False
            self.leave_type = False
            self.holiday = True
            self.weekly_off = False
            self.compensation_date = False
        if self.attendance == 'weekly_off':
            self.present = False
            self.absent = False
            self.half_day = False
            self.late = False
            self.comp_off = False
            self.leave_type = False
            self.holiday = False
            self.weekly_off = True
            self.compensation_date = False
```

Comment: leave_type is selection field or boolean, what are option for leave_type

Comment: leave_type = fields.Selection([('casual_leave', 'Casual Leave'), 
                                         ('sick_leave', 'Sick Leave'),
                                         ('earned_leave', 'Earned Leave'),
                                         ('maternity_leave', 'Maternity Leave'),
                                         ('paternity_leave', 'Paternity Leave'),
                                         ('loss_of_pay', 'Loss of Pay')],
                                         sting='Leave Type', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am summing up your points.

1. Attendance = Present then Leave Type = Readonly.
2. Attendance = False then Leave Type = Required.
3. You are saving a record with Attendance = False and Leave Type = Sick Leave.(This is the value saved in DB).
4. Now you are trying to edit this record. Changing Attendance = True, Now the Leave Type = Readonly. So this field can't be updated using onchange method.

If you want to update this field value then you have to do it in the write method.

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    res = super(*yourmodel*, self).write(vals)
    if vals.get('attendance') and vals.get('attendance') == 'present':
        self.leave_type = False
    return res
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: I tried this method and it help to me but the one problem i facing is that the leave is getting false for the all the record but i want to false the particular record of the attendance ... please help for this situation ...Thanks

Comment: @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        print self, "SElf"
        print vals, "vals"
        res = super(ManualAttendanceLine, self).write(vals)
        if vals.get('attendance') and vals.get('attendance') != ('absent','half_day'):
            self.leave_type = False
#         if vals.get('attendance') and vals.get('attendance') !='half_day':
#             self.leave_type = False
        if vals.get('attendance') and vals.get('attendance') != 'comp_off':
            self.compensation_date = False
        return res